# Segmentation fault in shell program

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to create my own shell program and the tutorials I have been looking at advise the use of the **strtok()** function. Although, I am unable to get past simply parsing my command line and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I keep getting a **Segmentation Fault** during the first use of **strtok()** within the **parseCmd()** function.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAXSIZE 512

int parseCmd(char *cmd, char *args[])
{
    printf("LOGGER: parseCmd(cmd=%s, args=%p)\n", cmd, args);

    char cmdDelims[] = " >";

    char *cmdReader;
    cmdReader = strtok(cmd, cmdDelims);

    printf("LOGGER: cmdReader=%s\n", cmdReader);

    int i = 0;
    while (cmd != NULL)
    {
        printf("LOGGER: %d counter", i);

        args[i] = strdup(cmdReader);
        cmdReader = strtok(NULL, " >");
        i++;
    }
}

int main() 
{   
    char *in;
    in = malloc(MAXSIZE);

    char *args[10];
    char *cmd = NULL;

    int errorBit = 0;
    int terminationBit = 1;

    char inDelims[] = "\n";

    while (terminationBit)
    {
        printf("mysh>");
        fgets(in, MAXSIZE, stdin);

        cmd = strtok(in, inDelims);

        errorBit = parseCmd(cmd, args);
        if (errorBit)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot parse command %s\n", cmd);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (*args == "exit")
        {
            terminationBit = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help or advise on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Based on the output the **segfault actual may NOT be strtok()**.

*Here is some output:*

```
mysh>hi sup
LOGGER: parseCmd(cmd=hi sup, args=0x7fff50ec0b80)
LOGGER: cmdReader=hi
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Use valgrind. It will give needed information of memory errors and leaks to you. For more debug information like function and line where exact the problem is, compile your program with `-g` before running through valgrind.

Comment: do i just run the program normally after compiling it with -g or is there a special way to run the program via valgrind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple mistake:

```
while (cmd != NULL)
{
    // ...
}
```

...should probably be:

```
while (cmdReader != NULL)
{
    // ...
}
```

...since `cmd` will most likely never become `NULL`. Also, this:

```
if (*args == "exit")
{
    terminationBit = 0;
}
```

...probably is not going to do what you think. To compare strings, use:

```
if (strcmp(*args, "exit") == 0)
{
    terminationBit = 0;
}
```

You must make sure that `parseCmd` returns something as well, otherwise in this:

```
errorBit = parseCmd(cmd, args);
```

...`parseCmd` yields undefined behavior, so the value of `errorBit` is also completely undefined, as is your subsequent conditional that checks for its value.

Lastly, your program, as it is, will be leaking memory since you `strdup` and `malloc` and never free. Don't forget to `free` after you're done with `args`.

Comment: without even testing it, that is exactly what my issue must be. thanks